Sum all, ignoring first instance of value

I am having trouble creating a formula to sum all the values in column B, to ignore the first instance of the items in column A.  Desired output can be seen in column D and E.

Can you use help columns? I would add a column in column C (C2) that says =if(A2=A1,0,1) and add an additional sumifs condition against column C to exclude any 1's.

Here is one way of doing this:


=SUM(B$2:B$18*(MAP(A$2:A$18,LAMBDA(x, COUNTIF(x:$A$2,x)))>1)*(D2=A$2:A$18))


Or better use this formula to spill down:


=LET(α, A2:A18, MAP(D2:D4,LAMBDA(x, SUM(B2:B18*(α=DROP(VSTACK("",α),-1))*(x=α)))))


Or Combined output using one single dynamic array:


=LET(
     _Data, A2:B18,
     _Item, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _UniqItem, UNIQUE(_Item),
     _Hours, MAP(_UniqItem, LAMBDA(α, SUM(TAKE(_Data,,-1)*(DROP(VSTACK("",_Item),-1)=_Item)*(_Item=α)))),
     HSTACK(_UniqItem, _Hours))



Or use sumif() and index() with match() like so:
This will work with earlier versions of Excel which don't have lambda etc

as text:
SUMIF(A$2:A$18,D2,B$2:B$18)-INDEX(B$2:B$18,MATCH(D2,A$2:A$18,0))

Sumif() gets all the values, but the index with match only finds the first so subtract that result to leave you with the result you wish.
This might be easier to follow...

Another suggestion
=BYROW(D2:D4,LAMBDA(i,IFERROR(SUM(DROP(FILTER(B2:B18,A2:A18=i),1)),0)))


Use a SUMIFS and exclude the first instance from the sum range. The code below should give you what you want.
=SUMIFS($B$3:$B$18,$A$3:$A$18,D2)


Just for fun, convert the range to table (H) and add an index column



Item
Hours
Index

E





A
160
=SUM(--(INDEX([Item],1):[@Item]=[@Item]))

A
=SUMPRODUCT((H[Item]=E2)*H[Hours]*(H[Index]>1))


A
152


B



A
192


C



...
...







